# Implementing a virtual file by overriding Win32 File API

Tags: createfile, virtual-file

Is there any way to override Win32 File API such as CreateFile()? I want my app to see a virtual file solely for my app, however, the virtual file does not exist actually.

Comment: Do you need to manipulate the virtual file with standard Win32 APIs? I would create my own filesystem objects and functions if that is not a requirement which means that you can have it behave any way you want.

Comment: I already have my own one whose API is not standard Win32 APIs. I want my app which uses other library which cannot use my virtual file library be able to use my virtual file library. That's why I want to override Win32 file API.

Comment: How far did you get at? Please share! I seems that DLL injection can be done in some case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist two approaches - with a kernel-mode driver (documented one) and without such driver (a hacky way).

With a kernel-mode driver you have two ways - (1) create a virtual filesystem driver (or take existing one) and (2) create a filesystem filter driver (or take existing one). Driver development = a year or so of work to do right and completely. Driver development is fully documented in MSDN.

Without a kernel-mode driver you need to employ API hooking. Libraries such as Detours, MadCodeHook and Boxedapp SDK do this (and let you do this as well).

Hooking an API topic is quite large to describe it here fully, but there's a good [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

System-wide?  Bad idea.  If it's just your app, don't use the standard APIs and implement it yourself.  But if the data must persist between sessions, you'll have to store the data somewhere (file, registry, etc.).

Comment: Not system wide, but solely for my app. I already have a virtual file library, however, it cannot be used by other library which cannot access my virtual file library.